# --repeat comand doesn't work in Vlc.DotNet.WPF

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to retrieve the rtsp stream from my server, and when I disconnect vlc (after sending a Teardown request), I want the vlc to reconnect.
When run from the console (`vlc --repeat --rtsp-tcp rtsp://ip:port`) everything works. But when running from wpf application, the --repeat command doesn't work.

```
var libDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));

this.VlcControl.SourceProvider.CreatePlayer(libDirectory, new string[] { "--rtsp-tcp", "--repeat" });

string liveLink = $"rtsp://{ip}:{port}/{kid}";

this.VlcControl.SourceProvider.MediaPlayer.Play(liveLink);
```

already tried using the command `--loop` and `--insert-repeat=65535`

Nothing works.

Can anyone suggest a solution to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Declare a Delegate
    delegate void delegate_vlc_play(Uri file, string[] pars); 

    // Make sure to link the Event
    private void OnEndReached(object sender, Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayerEndReachedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (_AutoLoop) // private field of externally visible Property "AutoLoop"
        {
            // Get a new instance of the delegate
            delegate_vlc_play del_vlc = new delegate_vlc_play(myVLCControl.Play);
            // Call asyncroneously (save _CurrentFile somewhere when you call the Play() in the first place)
            del_vlc.BeginInvoke(new Uri(_CurrentFile), new string[] { }, null, null);
        }

    }
```

from https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues/96